# getAge in SQL depending on two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sql-date-functions

I am trying to calculate the age of a person depending on two dates. It works only for 50% of the people register in the data base and for the rest it just takes the first person's age.

Any idea where the problem could be?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAge ()
       RETURNS INT
       LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    $$
    SELECT CAST (
                (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE))
              - (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM birth_date)) AS INTEGER)
      FROM person;
    $$;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: I'm guessing PostgreSQL, he is using `$$`.

Comment: It's PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Postgres you can use [age function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
+----------------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| age(timestamp) | interval | Subtract from current_date (at midnight) | age(timestamp '1957-06-13') | 43 years 8 mons 3 days |
+----------------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
```

> ```
> select extract(year from age(timestamp '1957-06-13'))
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_part |
> | :-------- |
> | 59        |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7ff1fd8a38cc0e99c17cd3ca1bbffc3f)*

Comment: I already tried that and nothing changes. It only works in 50% of the code :/

Comment: Check your data, try to find some record where function doesn't works and post it here.

Comment: After inserting this data the code age function stops working

INSERT INTO Person (NAME,
                    BIRTH_DATE,
                    GENDER,
                    BIRTH_PLACE,
                    BIOGRAPHY,
                    ROLE,
                    MOVIE_TITLE)
     VALUES ('Alicia Vikander',
             '1988-10-03',
             'F',
             'Sweden',
             'Swedish actress, dancer and producer',
             'Producer',
             'Jason Bourne');

Answer (score 0):

There is a two-argument form of [`age()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) you can use for this

```
age(timestamp, timestamp)   interval
```

> Subtract arguments, producing a "symbolic" result that uses years and months, rather than just days   age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13') 43 years 9 mons 27 days

Using it is pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT age('1978-01-24'::date, '1972-02-24'::date);

       age       
-----------------
 5 years 11 mons
(1 row)
```

Comment: Still have the same problem using the function age :/ 50% works 50% doesn't

Comment: Hi Evan, I'm glad to see you again

Comment: @programer44 what 50% does not work. How about some actual details. Certainly the function isn't broke, it's you.

Answer (score -1):

Unix time might be what you're looking for:  use php to convert your date format to unix time, the highest number is the current time.convert birthdate as well, this will be a lower number... calculate the time with the two numbers you have and convert the unix time to the date format you'd like to use, this can be done with `php`